# Scale .htm file in UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm having some trouble with UIWebViews. I have a large PDF (96 pages) and it needs to be loaded inside a UIWebView, should be able to scroll to a certain part of it, and search in its text. So I figured converting it to .htm is a better solution. Now my problem is that the html only displays on half of the screen, on every iPhone size, and this is because of something the convertor did with it I think. 
[image]

Now the text is like this. How could I fix this? Is there any way to scale the content?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hasn't anyone got an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to fix this with CSS in your HTML documents. However as I don't know how your HTML code looks like here is a solution how to scale the HTML pages from the "outside":

The most obvious solution would be to set the zoom on the `UIWebView.scrollView`:

```
webview.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2
webview.scrollView.zoomScale = 2
```

But there is a big downside to this solution: The text becomes blurry because it is simply zoomed and not rendered at a bigger size. So this will not work.

However if you do the zooming directly in the HTML document the text will get rendered at a bigger size and stay sharp. Images on the other hand will get blurry using this method. But according to your screenshot you don't have images in your HTML, so this might work for you.

Set the `delegate` on the `UIWebView` to your ViewController and implement the following delegate method:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.style.zoom = 2.0")
}
```

This zooms the HTML document by the factor 2.0. You probably have to adjust the factor to your needs.